# Why Bitmap(Format8bppIndexed) need palette[256]?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Bitmap tempBmp = new Bitmap(10, 10,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

palette8bpp = tempBmp.Palette;

for (int i = 0; i < palette8bpp.Entries.Length; i++)

{

palette8bpp.Entries[i] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);

}

tempBmp.Dispose();

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

var bmpData=bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

bitmap.Palette = palette8bpp;

bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

this image is Have palette8bpp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcCil.jpg)

this image is not Have palette8bpp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0wpD.jpg)

When see two images, why Bitmap(Format8bppIndexed) need palette[256]???

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because it's **8 bits per pixel indexed**, the palette is provided as the color index.

Comment: The default palette seems to be for colored images, probably starting with the old EGA set of colors.. You need a fully grayscale palette for your image, so you need to create one.